# Как быстро сделать портфолио

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Как в кратчайшие сроки сделать портфолио?
Имеется опыт в разработке под PHP 3 года, laravel - 0.5 года. Активная работа - пол года. HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery, PHP, laravel, SQL. 
Нашел работу, требуют портфолио, за пол года был один проект - закрыт из-за нерентабельности, остались исходники beta версии, около 4 мелких заказов по настройке и доработке сайтов laravel и на различных CMS. Без фриланса. 
Что можно представить в портфолио? Что добавить - идей ноль, т.к. за пол года необходимое кол-во каких-то толковых проектов  и не набралось

Comment: Скажи, что у тебя много портфолио но везде NDA.

Comment: это конечно вариант, но все же временный. Я вот думаю что можно накидать

Comment: Вообще - это была шутка

Comment: Можешь написать чат на веб сокетах - это довольно таки быстро, а вообще если есть код на гитхаб то можешь его прикладывать

Comment: можно рассказать (вывести диалог как то на это) о том с чем работали какие технологии использовались, выпросить тестовое задание.
Можно попробовать поискать тестовое задание другой фирмы сделать и на github. 
Ещё можно взять список требований из вакансии, либо узнать на собеседовании про используемые технологии и проекты и попробовать успеть сделать с использованием всего либо части.
(если опыт 3.5 года есть то наверно нормально что нет портфолио, в основном договор о не разгашении подписывается и работаешь в команде например, откуда тогда портфолио (если вне работы что-то не делать) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имея старые исходники, выложи их в гитхаб.

Если нет ничего, что показать, то сделай парочку типовых решений с нуля.

Например:
-Сделай веб сервис для интеграции с Telegram.
-Либо найди какой-то API и сделай спец.интерфейс.
-Ну или например сделай бюджетный менеджер на PHP :)

Да бог с ним, сделай обычный портал с регистрацией и входом. Где можно постить что-то. Допустим простой чат с регистрацией.